# Building .vdproj with Visual Studio 2015 does not create output files (.msi)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vdproj

I am building vdproj with devenv. Command runs without errors, but no output with .msi files is generated, what am I doing wrong?

```
devenv "C:\Projects\MyProj\Main\Src\MyProj\MyProj.sln" 
/build "'PRO VERSION|Mixed Platforms'" 
/project "C:\Projects\MyProj\Main\Src\MyProj\MyProj.Setup\MyProj.Setup.vdproj"
/projectconfig "'PRO VERSION|Mixed Platforms'"
```

I am running it against **Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/devenv**

Comment: I am also facing the same, have you found any solution? Please let me know.

Comment: did u get the solution?? please post..its needful

Comment: I've added a powershell script which is what I use now, it works due to registry key, that was missing before. But if you add it manually, there is a big chance that windows or VS update will overwrite it again (happened to me numerous times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it working by adding the following registry value:

```
Try
{
    New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\MSBuild\" -Name "EnableOutOfProcBuild" -Value 00000000 -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
}
Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage2 = $_.Exception.Message
    "ERROR adding 'EnableOutOfProcBuild' registry value, error: $ErrorMessage2"
}
```

and then running following:

```
$devenv = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv";

    $config = "$ConfigurationMode|$Platform";
     & $devenv ($SolutionPath, "/project", $SetupProjectPath, "/build", "$config")
```